# dd-wrt (build build 23808) static IP for connected devices

Tags: dd-wrt

I have set a device in "**static leases**" to `192.168.1.102`. In the "**DHCP Clients**" the IP is that of the one above, yet when I try to access a webui for the services running they're on `192.168.1.128`? This was the original IP address that dd-wrt set and I have noticed that there's an * with that IP on "**Active Clients**". The device set to `192.168.1.102` is NOT on the "**Active Clients**" list.

How do I get the IP I want static to be on the IP I have chosen?

Answer (score 0):

I had to flush the DNS cache in order for the changes to take affect